# Hom and $\otimes$ functors on chain complexes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I can't solve the exercise $2.7.3$ from Weibel's book "An Introduction to homological algebra":

> Let $P,Q$ be right and left $R$-module chain complexes, $I$ be a cochain complex of abelian groups. Show that there is a natural isomorphism of double complexes:$$
> \operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}(\operatorname{Tot}^{\oplus}(P\otimes Q),I) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(P,\operatorname{Tot}^{\prod}\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}(Q,I)).
> $$

If I'm correct
$$
\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}(\operatorname{Tot}^{\oplus}(P\otimes Q),I)^{p,q}=\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}({\oplus}(P_i\otimes Q_{p-i}),I^q)={\prod}\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}(P_i\otimes Q_{p-i},I^q)
,$$
while 
$$
\operatorname{Hom_R}(P,\operatorname{Tot}^{\prod}\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}(Q,I)})^{p,q}=
\operatorname{Hom_R}(P_p,{\prod}\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}(Q_i,I^{q-i})})=\prod \operatorname{Hom_R}(P_p,\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}(Q_i,I^{q-i})})=\prod \operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}(P_p \otimes Q_i,I^{q-i}).$$ But these expressions are not equal. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're right.

I think what he means to ask for is a natural isomorphism of complexes
$$\operatorname{Tot}^{\prod}\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}}(\operatorname{Tot}^{\oplus}(P\otimes Q),I) \cong \operatorname{Tot}^{\prod}\operatorname{Hom_R}(P,\operatorname{Tot}^{\prod}\operatorname{Hom_{Ab}(Q,I)}).$$

Comment: Even then, I am [still unsure what he meant and what is actually correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802953)